# Should animations be locked to FPS or Fixed time

Tags: animation

I have been working on a 3D engine and I am now implementing animations, but I can't find out whether or not to use the FPS of the engine or a fixed time method for the transformation's speed. Could someone please tell me the standard for animation timing. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a fixed time for this. Consider the following: Your computer is super fast, you have high end hardware. Now you animate via FPS and make your animation look great. Let's say you had 120 fps.

Since you did great work, you want to show me. I have bad hardware, everything takes ages. I have to work with just 30 fps - sufficient to call it real-time, but not too nice. It will take four times to completely play your animation on my computer, because you made it follow the fps. Therefore it doesn't convince me at all.

This is even more problematic, if you do this in a multiplayer scenario. You could already start a new action after the animation, whereas I have to wait for the animation to finish. Therefore, there is an inconsistency in game state as well as an unfair game, because you can do things much faster.